# Is it possible that some Android phones do not receive GCM push?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an app, that sends push notifications to android and iOs devices via GCM.
It all works, users receive pushes, but today one of my users (7k kilometers away) said that she doesnt receive notifications.

We remotely checked everything:

1.pushes are enabled for my app (we even uninstalled it and installed back),

2.token is successfully received and saved on server,

3.google in response to push sent answers with

`[{"multicast_id":6200102626600584726,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1478850747416917%289a1a60289a1a60"}]}]`

wich seems ok and there no errors.

4.Applicaion is on the background.

But NO NOTIFICATION received anyway.

I dont know where to dig now - all my phones and phones of my friends/collegues receive pushes just fine. Andriod version is 5.1, Phone is Meizu m3 note (never seen one like this).

Can anyone advise what try next?

EDIT: gmail notifications work on her phone... Not sure, but I think that Google play is working fine and installed properly...

Comment: It could be that the device does not have Google Play Services / Framework installed. In this case, it would receive no notifications.

Comment: But she installs the app from Google Play

Comment: A quick search yielded this: https://forum.meizufans.eu/topic/5494/how-to-install-google-play-store-in-m3-note-with-flyme-os-version-chinese-firmware/2 `I will ask someone that is successful to install Google Play in Meizu M3 Note, please guide me how to install Google Play Store in Meizu M3 Note.` - It would seem likely that they have some "funny" set up on their phone.

Comment: You could give her a version that reports this: `boolean servicesAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;` to test if she has it available.

Comment: Cant really do this - I use phonegap.

Comment: If they are cooperative, you can ask them to check what version of `Google Services Framework` they have using their Apps list. I currently have `7.1.1`. Also what version of `Google Play services`. I currently have `9.8.77`.

Answer (score 1):

I am relatively certain that the user in question does not have a fully functional Google Play Services / Framework installed.

Their device seems to not include these as a [search on Google reveals](https://forum.meizufans.eu/topic/5494/how-to-install-google-play-store-in-m3-note-with-flyme-os-version-chinese-firmware/2):

> I will ask someone that is successful to install Google Play in Meizu M3 Note, please guide me how to install Google Play Store in Meizu M3 Note.

The best thing to do is to check with them if they have the services installed, and if they do, what version (is it current and updated?).

If not, see if they can install it or update it to the necessary version.

If that is still a no-go. They are likely a lost cause for using GCM.

Comment: we have found out that gmail notifications received just fine

Comment: Can you still ask them what version they have? Just to be certain.